# Can I make the glb file smaller?

Tags: gltf

I have a large `obj` file of `306 mb`. So I converted it into a `glb` file to reduce its size. The size of the file has decreased a lot to `82 mb`, but it is still big. I want to make this file smaller. Is there a way? If there is, please let me know.

If you can't reduce the `glb` file further, let me know more effective ways to reduce the `obj` file. One of the things I've already done is change the `obj` file to `json`, compress, unwind and load it using `pako.js`. I didn't choose this method because it was too slow to decompress.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There might be, if it is the vertex-data that is causing the file to be that big. In that case you can use the DRACO compression-library to get the size down even further.

First, to test the compressor, you can run

```
npx gltf-pipeline -i original.glb -d --draco.compressionLevel 10 -o compressed.glb
```

(you need to have a current version of node.js installed for this to work)

If vertex-data was the reason for the file being that big, the compressed file should be considerably smaller than the original.

Now you have to go through some extra-steps to load the file, as the regular GLTFLoader doesn't support DRACO-compressed meshes.

Essentially, you need to import the [`THREE.DRACOLoader`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/DRACOLoader.js) and the [draco-decoder](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/libs/draco). Finally, you need to tell your `GLTFLoader` that you know how to handle DRACO-compression:

```
DRACOLoader.setDecoderPath('path/to/draco-decoder');
gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(new DRACOLoader());
```

After that, you can use the GLTFLoader as before.

The only downside of this is that the decoder itself needs some resources: decoding isn't free and the decoder itself is another 320kB of data to be loaded by the browser. I think it's still worth it if it saves you megabytes of mesh-data.

Comment: To compress it you need to install node.js, then run npm install --global gltf-pipeline in a terminal.

Comment: @aLx13 you don't need to install it globally, you don't even need to install it at all. `npx` handles that for you and installs it temporarily.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned the obvious, simple way of lossily reducing the size of a `.glb` file that's just a container for separate mesh and texture data:

Reduce your vertex count by collapsing adjacent vertices that are close together or coplanar, and reduce your image data by trimming out, scaling down, or using a lower bit depth for unnecessary details.

Every 2X decrease in surface polygon/pixel density should yield roughly a 4X decrease in file size.

And *then*, once you've removed unneeded detail, start looking at things like `DRACO`, `basis`, fewer `JPEG` chroma samples, and `optipng`.

Comment: I have been searching around and was equally surprised that nobody is talking about just making the .glb smaller. I would like to do something like this to load preview 3D files that when opened point to the full size model but the preview is just a lossy reduced model.

Similarly if you have an 2400x2400px image on a mobile device, you can simply scale the image down to 640x640 with little/no perceived loss. Obviously 3D files are far less trivial, but same concept.

Any suggestions on how to go about this? preferably in node.js backend?

Comment: @AhrenFullStop Google for "Mesh decimation library" and "Mesh simplification library". If you can call external commands and don't mind overkill, you could also run Blender as a Python library and use its "Decimate" modifier to re-export the mesh— This can automatically take care of preserving UV mappings and such.